# TextView with Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS makes phone numbers invisible

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I'm populating a TextView with text and phone numbers, like so:

```
tv.setText("Here is a phone number: 1234567890.  OK?");
```

That appears fine in my emulator.  Now, I want to linkify the phone numbers, so I've done the following:

```
tv.setText("Here is a phone number: 1234567890.  OK?");
tv.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
```

This makes the phone number disappear and I see:

```
Here is a phone number:           .  OK?
```

It's basically showing the phone number but it's invisible.  If I touch the space where the (invisible) phone number is then Android loads up the dialer and dials 1234567890.  It's not that the phone number is white on white -- I've changed the background to red and it does not appear white on red -- it is invisible.

Any clues?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the `android:textColorLink` attribute on your `TextView`.